# Arabic language typing in tinymce

Tags: tinymce, arabic

I am using arabic language in tinymce with help of arabic font all it's working properly but i want to allow user to type arabic language i read so many thread it's just gave me solution for RTL ( right to left) and all toolbar and menubar also working RTL but user can't type arabic language in editor they can only type in english please help. Is there any plugin require for arabic language typing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Language Support and Localization in TinyMCE can mean many different things:

To make the TinyMCE UI a different language, take a look at UI language packs:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/localization/#language

https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/language-packages/

To set the directionality (left-to-right/right-to-left), look at the `directionality` configuration option:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/localization/#directionality

However to actually enter Arabic text into the TinyMCE editor, the user's computer would have to be properly configured to generate Arabic text. How to do this obviously varies by operating system, and it is not something within the purview of TinyMCE.